# Rmarkdown: cannot access to data saved in cache

Tags: r, r-markdown, rdata

I generate a report in Rmarkdown, where I use the option
    cache=TRUE
in order to save the simulated data frames generated in different chrunks. But when I go to the htlm folder where the data is stored, even though I see the .Rdata files and their corresponding sizes, which makes sense (about 3.1 kb), when I load the files on Rstudio, then there is nothing, the global enviroment remains empty.

I have really not idea why I cannot see the data.frames, any hint is appreciated.